# Command to fix internal org broken links in HTML export

Tags: org-export, regular-expressions

I'm trying to export a bunch of org entries with numerous internal links to an external website. These links get broken during the export, but I can mostly recreate the correct URLs with some simple Regex. I say "mostly", because I would like the text between the `<a></a>` HTML tags to be downcased unless the second word is capitalized, but I am unable to express this in my function. Here is what I have:

```
(defun my/function ()
  (interactive)
  (org-narrow-to-subtree)
  (org-html-export-as-html)
  ;; repair broken links
  (while (re-search-forward "\\(\\[BROKEN LINK: \\*\\)\\(.*?\\)\\(]\\)" nil t)
    (replace-match (concat "<A href=\"https://mywebsite.org/"
                   (downcase (replace-regexp-in-string "[ ,]" "-" (match-string 2))) ; replace spaces, commas with hyphens
                   "\">"
                   ;; RELEVANT CODE BELOW
                   (if (let ((case-fold-search nil))
                     (string-match ".* [A-Z]" (match-string 2)))
                       (match-string 2)
                     (downcase (match-string 2)))
                   ;; RELEVANT CODE ABOVE
                   "</A>")))
  (browse-url-of-buffer))
```

When I run this function, things work as intended if no links in the org heading(s) being exported satisfy the condition. However, if the condition is satisfied, I get the error `args out of range:0, 6`.

Comment: Why are there broken links?

Comment: Because they are internal links to other headings, of the form `[[id:5437B089-FEE2-46A7-9520-BE8E44C1FED4][link]]`.

Comment: The function turns these links into something like `<a href="https://website.org/link">link</a>`, and this works fine, except that there are some special cases where the text between the tags should appear capitalized, and I would like to know why the `if` statement in the function isn't working for these cases.

Comment: For debugging, do `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` and rerun. The resulting backtrace should tell you which function exactly gets the error, so you can look up its doc string and try to figure out what happened. The repeated use of `(match-string 2)` looks suspect to me, but I have not really looked at the code carefully.